# MongoDB - Search by first attr with value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Is it possible to do the same filtering as in JS?

```js
const list = [
  {
    a: 1,
    "mostImportant": "qwer",
    "lessImportant": "rty"
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    "lessImportant": "weRt",
    "notImportant": "asd",
    
  },
  {
    a: 3,
    "mostImportant": "qwe2",
    "notImportant": "asd",
    
  }
];

list.filter((data) => {
  data.attrToSearch = data.mostImportant || data.lessImportant || data.notImportant;
  
  return data.attrToSearch.match(/wer/i);
});
```

in MongoDB?

Loot at this example:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/VQdfoQ-HQV4

So I want `attrToSearch` to contain the value of the first, not blank attr with next order `mostImportant`, `lessImportant`, `notImportant`
and then match by regex.
The expected result is to receive the first two documents.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1: With [`$ifNull`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)**

**Updated**

`$ifNull` only checks whether the value is `null` but does not cover checking for the empty string.

Hence, according to the attached JS function which *skips* for `null`, `undefined`, empty string value and takes the following value, you need to **set the field value as `null`** if it is **found out with an empty string** via `$cond`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      mostImportant: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$mostImportant",
              ""
            ]
          },
          then: null,
          else: "$mostImportant"
        }
      },
      lessImportant: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$lessImportant",
              ""
            ]
          },
          then: null,
          else: "$lessImportant"
        }
      },
      notImportant: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$notImportant",
              ""
            ]
          },
          then: null,
          else: "$notImportant"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "attrToSearch": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$mostImportant",
          "$lessImportant",
          "$notImportant"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      attrToSearch: {
        $regex: "wer",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Approach 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BBPeWAnYa-g)

---

**Approach 2: With [`$function`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)**

Via `$function`, it allows you to write a user-defined function (UDF) with JavaScript support.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "attrToSearch": {
        $function: {
          body: "function(mostImportant, lessImportant, notImportant) { return mostImportant || lessImportant || notImportant; }",
          args: [
            "$mostImportant",
            "$lessImportant",
            "$notImportant"
          ],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      attrToSearch: {
        $regex: "wer",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Approach 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/drGWKRkdxUg)

Comment: Great. It covers almost all cases except blank string. Is there any better way to ignore blank strings than add $cond for all of them?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/VLQJJI5my5F
or
https://mongoplayground.net/p/rTNnqHKhVVR

Comment: Ya, sorry for that the `||` operator in JS include checking of `null`, `undefined` and "" (empty string). If you use `$ifNull`, it only checks for `null` value but bypass for empty string. One approach is that you need to set empty string to `null` as what you have done in the provided link. Another approach with `$function` with you can write the JS function. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wKJ4LRF7Hfw)